# Asyncronous console with task controlling

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, console, task-parallel-library

Please help me find the right solution.
The main problem the waiting completion of the program **through the console**, and at the same time monitor tasks.

I wrote some prototype, but I am not sure that is effective - in this approach, we spend an extra thread of waiting for action from the console. I do not see alternatives, since Console does not support asynchronous (some sort of **Console.ReadLineAsync**).

UPDATE:
I have two working Tasks (*task1, task2*).They simulate some real work.
The program is a console. So we need to give user a chance to stop the program.By default in consoles, this is done via the expectation of pressing "Enter" (through *consoleTask*).

The question is. How to wait for the completion of worker threads AND Monitor stop command from the user.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  CancellationTokenSource mycts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
  {
  // doing some work, that can throw exception
  Thread.Sleep(1000);

  // how to avoid this closuring ?
  mycts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
  }).ContinueWith((_) => mycts.Cancel()); // Do I need caching this task?

  var task2 = Task.Run(() =>    
  {
  // doing some work, that can throw exception
  Thread.Sleep(5000);

  // again closuring
  mycts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
  }).ContinueWith((_) => mycts.Cancel()); // Do I need caching this task?


  // I do not know how to do better with Console !!
  var consoleTask = Task.Factory.StartNew((cts) =>
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
  Console.ReadLine();
  }, mycts).ContinueWith((_) => mycts.Cancel()); // Do I need caching this task?

  // Waiting for the Completion or Exception
  Task.WaitAny(task1, task2, consoleTask);

  // Now waiting for the completion of workflow
  try
  {
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // log faulted tasks
  }

  //Exit
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a `Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);` because if the `WaitAny` returns because of an exception, then you will require to hit enter to exit. (it will make you hit enter like crazy, just in case there was an exception that was thrown silently)

Comment: Really? I expected that after the exception handling block, the program will be completed correctly. Hmm

Comment: It will complete correctly,  but you explicitly ask to go to the  end of all the tasks.  I haven't tried it though,  but that's what it looks like.  I might be wrong

Answer (score 2):

There's a few guidelines you should follow:

1. Do not use `ContinueWith`. Use `await` instead.
2. Do not use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Use `Task.Run` instead.
3. Do not mix blocking and asynchronous code. In the case of a console application, it's generally best to just have `Main` call a `MainAsync` and wait on the returned task. For most applications, that's the only blocking you should use.

I'm not sure what `how to avoid this closuring?` means.

In the case of `ReadLine` (and other Console methods), you are correct, there are unfortunately no asynchronous methods. It *might* work to use a separate thread, but the `Console` class (more particularly, the Console input and output streams) have some unusual locking going on under the covers, so I'm not *positive* this would work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MainAsync().Wait();
}
static CancellationTokenSource mycts = new CancellationTokenSource();
static async Task MainAsync()
{
  try
  {
    var task1 = CancelAfterSuccessfulCompletionAsync(
        Task.Run(() => SomeWorkThatCanThrowException()));
    var task2 = CancelAfterSuccessfulCompletionAsync(
        Task.Run(() => OtherWorkThatCanThrowException()));
    var consoleTask = CancelAfterSuccessfulCompletionAsync(
        Task.Run(() => MonitorConsole()));
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, consoleTask);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
  }
}
static void OtherWorkThatCanThrowException()
{
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  mycts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
}
static void SomeWorkThatCanThrowException()
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  mycts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
}
static void MonitorConsole()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
static async Task CancelAfterSuccessfulCompletionAsync(Task task)
{
  await task;
  mycts.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Will we get "Closure" on "mycts" in this code ?
And how to avoid it?



    CancellationTokenSource mycts;
    var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
      mycts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
    });

Comment: @SoaperPlus: Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem with the Closure.

Here very interesting reading "TPL Performance Improvements in .NET 4.5"
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235962.aspx

in chapter "Encode closure information into a Task’s state object ".

Comment: @SoaperPlus: You don't need to do that. There's no "problem" there.

Answer (score 1):

Since console doesn't have a SynchronizationContext there's not much you can do without blocking the main thread while your async operations are executing.

However, it's much simpler if you just write your code as if it's asynchronous and block in the simplest possible way. I would suggest moving all your code into an async `MainAsync` and blocking once:

```
static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    // manage tasks asynchronously
}
```

What you can do, instead of blocking, is use a custom context for executing asynchronous operations like [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext). This allows you to avoid blocking synchronously on a `Task`:

```
static void Main()
{
    AsyncContext.Run(MainAsync);
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I need.
I need to somehow provide the user with a stop command in the console (ie "Press Enter to exit"). 

How do you propose to do that?